# How to pass extra request parameter in OAUTH with SOAP UI (Open Source)

Tags: oauth, soapui, oauth-2.0

Using SOAP UI , I added OAUTH 2 functionality . But i need to pass extra parameter rather than Client id ,Secret ,Access & Callback Url and Scope .

[image]

For my project , additionality I need to pass a extra paramater. Is it possible in SOAP UI ?

Comment: Is it just possible to use `rest request` test step?

Comment: Yes. I created test step using rest request using oauth2 .

Comment: If you need to send additional parameters, you should be able to set from `rest request` step. Or something else is your case?

Comment: i need to pass extra param while getting a access token using oauth2 authentication not rest request .